# Prevent user from refreshing page to add blank value in php/sql

Tags: php, sql

config.php is the global file which has the connection codes.

my UPDATED Insert.php code is:

```
<?php

include("config.php");

if (isset($_POST[firstname]) && isset($_POST[lastname]) && isset($_POST[age])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
    mysql_query($sql, $connect); 
    header("Location: add.htm");
    // "1 record added";
}

else {
    echo "No record added";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5;url=add.htm\"/>";
}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$connect))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

my View.php code is:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $results['FirstName'] . ', ' . $results['LastName'] . ', ' . $results['Age'] . '<br/>';
}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$connect))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

my Config.php code is:

```
<?php

$dbhost="MYWEBHOST";
$dbusername="MYUSERNAME";
$dbpassword="MYPASSWORD";
$dbname="MYDATABASE";

$connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect) or die ("Could not connect to database");

?>
```

Insert.php display the message "1 record added" and redirect the user back to the html form. Which is working fine but I do not want to add duplicate/blank values when the user to either refresh or come directly to Insert.php. How do I accomplish this in the existing Insert.php code?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Are you referring to the Config.php file? so to clarify I can't use mysql_connect()? What would be the replacement?

Comment: I edited the connect command and let me if it's correct now.

Comment: It's not correct. You're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_`. The blue links will take you the appropriate api's

Comment: so anywhere i have MYSQL, should be MYSQLi?

Comment: Sort of. You need to make sure you're using the API correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a meta redirect, do a header redirect

```
echo "1 record added";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"10;url=add.htm\"/>";
```

Do the following

```
header("Location: add.htm");
```

If you redirect them, then if they hit back it won't be sending post data and you should be a-ok.

Comment: i get this error when i add the code: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/web/i/imc.com/htdocs/search/insert.php:8) in /home/web/i/imc.com/htdocs/search/insert.php on line 9"

Comment: And i did refresh the page a couple of times and it still added the record, which i am trying to prevent :) What i am really looking for is if a user refreshes the page or comes directly to this URL, it should either redirect to the html form without adding anything to the table or just refresh without adding anything to the table

Comment: You can only do a header redirect if you haven't written anything to the body yet.  Header redirects have to be done before you echo ANYTHING :)

Comment: Common practice is after processing the form is to redirect to a new page to avoid the whole process of refreshing / reposting.  The idea being if the user is redirected, if they hit back there is no data in $_POST so you won't re-insert the record

Comment: Stephen Flee, I updated the Insert.php file. Now when I go to my form (add.htm) and hit submit, it's entering the values twice in View.php :(

Comment: Hrmn I can't think of any reason why it would insert it TWICE...that is strange.  I would also take out the meta redirect on your else statement too (header is always better)

You'll also want to use the mysqli function too (mysql is going to be depricated) and if you want to pass data from insert.php to view.php you can do it over $_SESSION (just make sure you call session_start() first)

I know it's a lot to process right away, but if you start with the best practices you'll save yourself a lot of pain down the road :)

Comment: Damn it, now it's another problem! :(((((

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24924/discussion-between-stephen-flee-and-sikni8)